# How to Replace prefixes and Namespaces in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a source XML like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns2:ArrayOfImportNotice xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IPL.ContractsFinder.BusinessEntities.Import">
<ns2:ImportNotice>
    <ns2:IsPublished>true</ns2:IsPublished>
    <ns2:Notice>
        <ns2:AnnexDOption xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:ApproachMarketDate xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:CPVDescription xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:ContactDetails>
            <ns2:Address1>1 Dermant Street</ns2:Address1>
            <ns2:Address2>Frixton</ns2:Address2>
            <ns2:Country>UK</ns2:Country>
            <ns2:Email>no-reply@ansmtp.ariba.com</ns2:Email>
            <ns2:Name>Alex Reed</ns2:Name>
            <ns2:Phone>07777 123456</ns2:Phone>
            <ns2:Postcode>AX1 1PP</ns2:Postcode>
            <ns2:Town>Anborough</ns2:Town>
            <ns2:WebAddress>www.areedsite.co.uk</ns2:WebAddress>
        </ns2:ContactDetails>
        <ns2:CpvCodes>
            <string>44618420</string><string>44618420</string>
        </ns2:CpvCodes>
        <ns2:DeadlineDate>2020-11-27T02:55:00</ns2:DeadlineDate>
        <ns2:Description>Head Parts for the Bicycle</ns2:Description>
        <ns2:End>2021-06-01T00:00:00</ns2:End>
        <ns2:Id xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:Identifier>7033000452-Doc159623264-177772773</ns2:Identifier>
        <ns2:IsExtensionPossible>false</ns2:IsExtensionPossible>
        <ns2:IsFrameworkAgreement>false</ns2:IsFrameworkAgreement>
        <ns2:IsSuitableForSme>true</ns2:IsSuitableForSme>
        <ns2:IsSuitableForVco>false</ns2:IsSuitableForVco>
        <ns2:SupplyChain>false</ns2:SupplyChain>
        <ns2:LastNotifiableUpdate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ns2:LastNotifiableUpdate>
        <ns2:LinkReason xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:Location>
            <ns2:Lat>0</ns2:Lat>
            <ns2:Lon>0</ns2:Lon>
        </ns2:Location>
        <ns2:Nationwide xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:OjeuContractType>Works</ns2:OjeuContractType>
        <ns2:OrganisationName>Cumulus GSA</ns2:OrganisationName>
        <ns2:ParentId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:ParentIdentifier xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:Postcode xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:ProcedureType>Open</ns2:ProcedureType>
        <ns2:PublishedDate>2021-02-12T07:05:00</ns2:PublishedDate>
        <ns2:ReasonContractLawful xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:Region/>
        <ns2:Sector xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:SpendProfile xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ns2:Start>2021-02-12T07:05:00</ns2:Start>
        <ns2:Status>Open</ns2:Status>
        <ns2:Title>Head Parts</ns2:Title>
        <ns2:Type>Contract</ns2:Type>
        <ns2:ValueHigh>150.00</ns2:ValueHigh>
        <ns2:ValueLow>100.00</ns2:ValueLow>
    </ns2:Notice>
    <ns2:WithdrawnDate xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <ns2:WithdrawnReason xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</ns2:ImportNotice></ns2:ArrayOfImportNotice>
```

I need to transform the XML to the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ArrayOfImportNotice xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IPL.ContractsFinder.BusinessEntities.Import">
<ImportNotice>
    <IsPublished>true</IsPublished>
    <Notice>
        <AnnexDOption i:nil="true" />
        <ApproachMarketDate i:nil="true" />
        <CPVDescription i:nil="true" />
        <ContactDetails>
            <Address1>1 Dermant Street</Address1>
            <Address2>Frixton</Address2>
            <Country>UK</Country>
            <Email>no-reply@ansmtp.ariba.com</Email>
            <Name>Alex Reed</Name>
            <Phone>07777 123456</Phone>
            <Postcode>AX1 1PP</Postcode>
            <Town>Anborough</Town>
            <WebAddress>www.areedsite.co.uk</WebAddress>
        </ContactDetails>
        <CpvCodes xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <d3p1:string>44618420</d3p1:string>
            <d3p1:string>51542000</d3p1:string>
        </CpvCodes>
        <DeadlineDate>2020-11-27T02:55:00</DeadlineDate>
        <Description>Head Parts for the Bicycle</Description>
        <End>2021-06-01T00:00:00</End>
        <Id i:nil="true" />
        <Identifier>OPP0001-A</Identifier>
        <IsExtensionPossible>false</IsExtensionPossible>
        <IsFrameworkAgreement>false</IsFrameworkAgreement>
        <IsSuitableForSme>true</IsSuitableForSme>
        <IsSuitableForVco>false</IsSuitableForVco>
        <SupplyChain>false</SupplyChain>
        <LastNotifiableUpdate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</LastNotifiableUpdate>
        <LinkReason i:nil="true" />
        <Location>
            <Lat>0</Lat>
            <Lon>0</Lon>
        </Location>
        <Nationwide i:nil="true" />
        <OjeuContractType>Works</OjeuContractType>
        <OrganisationName>Petra Corp</OrganisationName>
        <ParentId i:nil="true" />
        <ParentIdentifier i:nil="true" />
        <Postcode i:nil="true" />
        <ProcedureType>Open</ProcedureType>
        <PublishedDate>2021-02-12T07:05:00</PublishedDate>
        <ReasonContractLawful i:nil="true" />
        <Region/>
        <Sector i:nil="true" />
        <SpendProfile i:nil="true" />
        <Start>2021-02-12T07:05:00</Start>
        <Status>Open</Status>
        <Title>Head Parts</Title>
        <Type>Contract</Type>
        <ValueHigh>150.00</ValueHigh>
        <ValueLow>100.00</ValueLow>
    </Notice>
    <WithdrawnDate i:nil="true" />
    <WithdrawnReason i:nil="true" />
</ImportNotice>
```

So I am trying to accomplish below changes.

1. Only remove the `ns2:` prefix and retain the namespace.
2. Replace the `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` namespace for each of the elements in which its present into the namespace `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` on the root node and have prefix reference `"i:"` for each of those same elements.
3. Specify the namespace `xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"` for the element CpvCodes and then have its reference for the child elements.

So far I have tried to remove the `ns2:` prefix and set namespace for  element using below xslt.

```
e<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IPL.ContractsFinder.BusinessEntities.Import" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IPL.ContractsFinder.BusinessEntities.Import"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/><xsl:template match="string"><xsl:element name="d3p1:{local-name()}" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:element</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns2:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces the result halway, not sure how i can achieve all the required changes.
I am quite new to XSLT, any help is appreciated.
Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
  <xsl:template match="ns2:*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

plus

```
  <xsl:template match="@xsi:*" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <xsl:attribute name="i:{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

plus

```
  <xsl:template match="ns2:CpvCodes">
      <CpvCodes xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IPL.ContractsFinder.BusinessEntities.Import" xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </CpvCodes>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ns2:CpvCodes//*">
      <xsl:element name="d3p1:{local-name()}" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4uV